# Magento: How have I to get all the transaction payment items of a specific order?

Tags: php, magento

How have I to get all the transaction payment items of a specific order in Magento?

I can get the last Transaction Id only:

```
$transId = $order->getPayment()->getLastTransId();
```

is there a way to get all the order transaction?

[image: This is the information that I need]

thanks

Comment: sorry for mis-understanding. So, you want all transaction payment items like credit card information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem!

I have solved in this way!

```
$transaction = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()
                                                                         ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $payment->getOrder()->getEntityId()))
                                                                         ->addAttributeToFilter('txn_type', array('eq' => 'capture'));
```

this is the result:

```
array(2) {
  ["totalRecords"] => int(1)
  ["items"] => array(1) {
    [0] => array(10) {
      ["transaction_id"] => string(2) "62"
      ["parent_id"] => NULL
      ["order_id"] => string(2) "89"
      ["payment_id"] => string(2) "89"
      ["txn_id"] => string(16) "3060630120986423"
      ["parent_txn_id"] => NULL
      ["txn_type"] => string(7) "capture"
      ["is_closed"] => string(1) "1"
      ["additional_information"] => array(0) {
      }
      ["created_at"] => string(19) "2013-08-19 09:36:07"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: I was missing toArray call `var_dump(array('transactions' => $transactions->toArray()));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getPaymentInfo();
```

will give you all payment info

Comment: This is not correct. This method helps you to get the main array payment information.

Comment: please look the screenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Grid code you have on the screenshot. Works for me:

```php
$transactions =     Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_payment_transaction_collection');
$transactions->addOrderIdFilter($order->getId());
$transactions->addOrderInformation(array('increment_id'));
$transactions->addPaymentInformation(array('method'));

foreach ( $transactions as $t) {
        var_dump( $t->debug() );
}
```